# How do I pick most recent record for each company for each statement date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that stores different company's financial information for each financial statement date. Company A has records for 12/31/2016, 12/31/2015, and so on. My database also stores multiple records for each statement date per company if someone edits that record, such as if someone made a typo in the Cash line of the Balance Sheet for 12/31/2016. In this case, Company A would have two records for 12/31/2016, one for the initial entry and the latest one including the edit.

My query currently pulls every record for every 12 month statement date including all records for updates. I tried to insert a Rank so that it pulls only the most recent record for each statement date for each company, but then the query only pulls the most recent record for that company overall, ignoring prior statement dates.

My ideal results would be to have something like this:

COMPANY A  | 12/31/16 | other info

COMPANY A  | 12/31/15 | other info

COMPANY A  | 12/31/14 | other info

COMPANY B  | 12/31/16 | other info

currently without Rank, it pulls:

**Stmt_id| company | FS_date | fs_id | num_of_months | KSOR | last_update | rank**

000001   | Comp A | 2018-03-31 | 1001 | 12 | KSOR | 2018-04-06 14:24:49.227 | 1

000002 | Comp A | 2018-03-31 | 1001 |   12 | KSOR | 2018-04-06 10:49:22.530 | 2

000013 | Comp B| 2018-01-31 | 2002 |12  | KSOR | 2018-03-07 14:32:04.843 | 28

000015| Comp B  | 2018-01-31 |  2002 | 12 | KSOR| 2018-03-07 12:48:34.533 | 29

000016| Comp B| 2018-01-31| 2002 | 12 | KSOR |  2018-03-07 12:20:08.180 | 30

**Here is my query:**

```
WITH CTE
AS (
SELECT [Stmt_ID]
,[Company]
,[fs_date]
,[fs_ID]
,[NUMBER_OF_MONTHS]
,[KSOR]
,[LAST_update]

,RANK() OVER (
PARTITION BY [fs_date] ORDER BY [stmt_ID] DESC
) AS RANKNUM

FROM [dbo].[SIRV] 
)
Select *
FROM CTE 
WHERE RANKNUM = 1 AND [NUMBER_OF_MONTHS] = 12 
order by [fs_date] desc
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered so many times. Instead of RANK take a look at ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: Thank you Sean, but when I try I get the same results as with the Rank. Row number is returning the top row per company and is leaving out the other financial statement dates. Is there another way I can structure the Row_Number to make sure each company is pulling one record for each financial statement date?

Comment: You are partitioning by just STMT_DATE_ACTUAL. If you want to partition by company, shouldn't Company be there too?

Comment: Thank you Aaron, this seems to have worked! I appreciate the help. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You need the right `partition by`:

```
WITH CTE AS (
       SELECT s.*,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY company, fs_date
                                 ORDER BY stmt_ID DESC
                                ) as seqnum
      FROM [dbo].[SIRV] s
     )
SELECT CTE.*
FROM CTE 
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND NUMBER_OF_MONTHS = 12 
ORDER BY fs_date DESC;
```